# VBA to extract multiple zip files

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

I am working on VBA where I need to extract all zip files which are in same folder.  I need to be able to extract each zip file to extract to it respective folder(folder needs to be created based on zip file name).

Based on the below code, I am able to extract the first zip file and then running into error for "myFile - Dir" code

Please can someone help here

```
Sub Unzip()
Dim oApplicationlication As Object
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim ZipFile As Variant
Dim ExtractTo As Variant


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Cell B2 is the folder path which contains all zip file

MyFolder = Range("B2")
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.zip")
ZipFile = Range("C2")
ExtractTo = Range("B3")

Do While MyFile <> ""

'Cell C2 is updated with a zip file name via loop function

Range("C2") = MyFolder & "\" & MyFile

 If Len(Dir(Range("B3"), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
   MkDir Range("B3")
End If

 Set oApplication = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
 oApplication.Namespace(ExtractTo).CopyHere oApplication.Namespace(ZipFile).Items
 DoEvents

MyFile = Dir

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that you are using a `Dir` function inside of the loop (to see if the folder exists) as well as at the end (to advance to the next file). (You cant do that) Instead, use a `FileSystemObject` to check if the directory exists. This line `If Len(Dir(Range("B3"), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then` needs to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your exact same code using a file system object instead to do the folder work inside the loop. I didn't test it, but it illustrates what I am talking about in my comment above. You should be able to get it working using this:

```
Sub Unzip()
Dim oApplicationlication As Object
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim ZipFile As Variant
Dim ExtractTo As Variant

' create the fso
Dim fso as Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Cell B2 is the folder path which contains all zip file

MyFolder = Range("B2")
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.zip")
ZipFile = Range("C2")
ExtractTo = Range("B3")

Do While MyFile <> ""

'Cell C2 is updated with a zip file name via loop function

Range("C2") = MyFolder & "\" & MyFile


' use the fso to check for and create the folder
' this way you dont have to use the DIR function again, which was messing things up
If Not fso.FolderExists(Range("B3")) Then
   fso.CreateFolder(Range("B3"))
End If

 Set oApplication = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
 oApplication.Namespace(ExtractTo).CopyHere oApplication.Namespace(ZipFile).Items
 DoEvents

MyFile = Dir

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

You may also benefit (speed-wise, depending on how many zip files there are) from moving this line outside of the loop and put it at the top where the fso object is created.

```
Set oApplication = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
```

Comment: This is the conclusion I also reach. A second `Dir` (used to create the folder with the archive name if not exist) will stop the way in which initial `Dir` works. I wanted to post a similar code using `fso.FolderExists()` but now, no point to do that. This was the trick making the code working proper.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing because you are using `Dir` within the loop to check the existence of the folder to extract to. Instead, move that piece of code to outside the loop:

```
Sub Unzip()
    Dim oApplication As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim ExtractTo As Variant
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Cell B2 is the folder path which contains all zip file
    If Len(Dir(Range("B3"), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir Range("B3")
    End If
    MyFolder = Range("B2")
    If Right(MyFolder, 1) <> "\" Then MyFolder = MyFolder & "\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder, vbNormal)
    ExtractTo = Range("B3")
    Do While MyFile <> ""
    'Cell C2 is updated with a zip file name via loop function
        If Right(MyFile, 3) = "zip" Then
            Range("C2") = MyFolder & MyFile
            Set oApplication = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            oApplication.Namespace(ExtractTo).CopyHere oApplication.Namespace(MyFolder & MyFile).Items
            DoEvents
        End If
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking into this. I have moved the code "MyFile = Dir" outside the loop but that is looping through only the first zip file from the folder and going on and on with the same file.

Comment: That is because you are only telling the code to extract `ZipFile`, which is declared outside the loop and never updated. Try replacing `ZipFile` in the loop with `MyFolder & "\" & MyFile`.

Comment: That's because he didn't read your question very well. This code will not do what you want.

Comment: Code updated to move the location of the `MkDir` function to before the initialization of `MyFile`, and replaced `ZipFile` with `MyFolder & MyFile`. Tested it and it works.

Comment: A new folder needs to be created for each zip file... This part of the question... `(folder needs to be created based on zip file name).`